# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "literal_string to "string storage pointer"

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm developing dummy test contract in solidity with truffle, for below code,

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/SkillDevelopment.sol";

contract TestSkillDevelopment {
    SkillDevelopment skillDevelopmentContract = SkillDevelopment(DeployedAddresses.SkillDevelopment());
    function testSetStudentEnrollInfo() public {
        skillDevelopmentContract.setStudentEnrollInfo("{\"Info\":[{\"id\":\"06bb05b8b3152b0323f4a9c07ae84f0c513b24946a8f8ec685af7cd763f7ffad\",\"studentId\":6532916,\"parenterId\":6187778,\"schemeId\":3853115,\"batchId\":3458926,\"instructorId\":1175723,\"trainingId\":2599715,\"studentSkillState\":1,\"state\":1}]}");
        string expected = string("{\"Info\":[{\"id\":\"06bb05b8b3152b0323f4a9c07ae84f0c513b24946a8f8ec685af7cd763f7ffad\",\"studentId\":6532916,\"parenterId\":6187778,\"schemeId\":3853115,\"batchId\":3458926,\"instructorId\":1175723,\"trainingId\":2599715,\"studentSkillState\":1,\"state\":1}]}");
        Assert.equal(skillDevelopmentContract.getStudentEnrollInfo(), expected, "The message should be set");
    }

}
```

but getting error

> " TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "literal_string  to "string storage pointer"."

while running "truffle test" command.

Please suggest, how is incorrect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
string memory expected = "{\"Info\":[{\"id\":\"06bb05b8b3152b0323f4a9c07ae84f0c513b24946a8f8ec685af7cd763f7ffad\",\"studentId\":6532916,\"parenterId\":6187778,\"schemeId\":3853115,\"batchId\":3458926,\"instructorId\":1175723,\"trainingId\":2599715,\"studentSkillState\":1,\"state\":1}]}";
```

The default location for a `string` is `storage`, which would mean you would have to point it at some state variable in storage. Switching to `memory` solves that issue. Finally, the explicit cast to `string` is unneeded (because the value is already a string) and causes the compilation error you saw.